# Auto scaling Mongodb as a service on Microsoft Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure

I see a MongoDB service in Microsoft Azure but that deploys a VM and installs MongoDB in that. I am guessing this will not auto scale and also charge me for the entire VM and MongoDB management (not just for my usage).

Is there any managed MongoDB as a service available in Microsoft Azure which will:

a) Auto scale. b) Charge me only for my usage.

I see MongoDB container image by Bitnami but I might have to deploy this on Helm.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mongo db atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) is managed mongo, you can use that, but it wont be billed through Azure Subscription and it wont appear on your subscription. But it can be deployed to the same azure region your resources live in

Comment: Yes. I am aware of MongoDB Atlas. But I already have an Azure subscription and want to use the same for MongoDB. Will I get a managed MongoDB service in Azure? What are my options here if I want to use Azure?

Comment: Okay. Other than MongoDB atlas, is there any other cloud platform which provides managed mongo (AWS, GCP, etc.)?

Comment: sorry, I'm not aware of that, only work with Azure ;)